# python pandas get index boundaries from a series of Booleans

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying cut videos based on some caracteristics.
My current strategy leads on a `pandas` series of booleans for each frame, indexed by timestamp. `True` to keep it, `False` to dump it.

As I plan to cut videos, i need to extract boundaries from this list, so that i can tell fmpeg beginning and end of the parts I want to extract from the main video.

Tu sum up :

I have a `pandas` Series which looks like this:

```
acquisitionTs
0.577331     False
0.611298     False
0.645255     False
0.679218     False
0.716538     False
0.784453      True
0.784453      True
0.818417      True
0.852379      True
0.886336      True
0.920301      True
0.954259     False
             ...  
83.393376    False
83.427345    False
dtype: bool
```

(truncated for presenting reasons, but the TimeStamp usually begins at 0)

and I need to get boundaries of `True` sequences, so in this example i should get `[[t_0,t_1],[t_2,t_3]n, ... [t_2n-1,t_2n]]` , with `t_0 = 0.784453` and `t_1 = 0.920301` if I have `n` different sequences of `True` in my pandas Series.

Now that probleme seems very simple, in fact you can just shift the sequence by one and a make a xor between the to get a list of boolean with `True` being for boundaries

```
e = df.shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)^df
print(e[e].index)
```

(with `df` being a pandas Series)
there is still some work to do, like figuring if first element is a rising edge or a falling edge, but this hack works.

However that doesn't seem very pythonic. In fact, the probleme is so simple I believe that there must be somewhere in `pandas`, `numpy` or even `python` a prebuilt function for this which would fit nicely in a single function call instead of a hack like above. The `groupby` function seems promising though, but i never used it before.

How would be the best way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a Dataframe rather than a Series (it actually works with a Series as well).

```
df
    acquisitionTs  Value
0        0.577331  False
1        0.611298  False
2        0.645255  False
3        0.679218  False
4        0.716538  False
5        0.784453   True
6        0.784453   True
7        0.818417  False
8        0.852379   True
9        0.886336   True
10       0.920301   True
11       0.954259  False
```

and I would do:

```
df[df.Value.diff().fillna(False)]
    acquisitionTs  Value
5        0.784453   True
7        0.818417  False
8        0.852379   True
11       0.954259  False
```

So as you know the first Value False here, you know that 0-4 is False and then it switch at every index (5,7,8,11)

The `groupby` function will not help you I think, since it will loose the order of your True/False values (you'll have 2 groups, instead of 5 in my example).

Comment: Nice for using resources at your disposal instead of introducing extraneous dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the answer ! However your code does not seem agnostic to the the first element, which can be True or False, so you would end with the opposite of what you wanted first.
An easy fix would be to insert the first row to your result if it is True (same occurs for the last row)
Thanks for the help anyway !

EDIT: Actually we can just watch the Value of the first (and the last) element of the result which tells if the edge is rising or falling, so there was not really a problem at first.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) to identify the clusters of `True`s:

```
In [102]: ts
Out[102]: 
0.069347    False
0.131956    False
0.143948    False
0.224864    False
0.242640     True
0.372599    False
0.451989    False
0.462090    False
0.579956     True
0.588791     True
0.603638    False
0.625107    False
0.642565    False
0.708547    False
0.730239    False
0.741652    False
0.747126     True
0.783276     True
0.896705     True
0.942829     True
Name: keep, dtype: bool

In [103]: groups, nobs = ndimage.label(ts); groups
Out[103]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Once you have the `groups` array, you can find the associated times using [`groupby/agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
    result = (df.loc[df['group'] != 0]
                .groupby('group')['times']
                .agg({'start':'first','end':'last'}))
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
np.random.seed(2016)

def make_ts(N, ngroups):
    times = np.random.random(N)
    times = np.sort(times)
    idx = np.sort(np.random.randint(N, size=(ngroups,)))
    arr = np.zeros(N)
    arr[idx] = 1
    arr = arr.cumsum()
    arr = (arr % 2).astype(bool)
    ts = pd.Series(arr, index=times, name='keep')
    return ts

def find_groups(ts):
    groups, nobs = ndimage.label(ts)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'times': ts.index, 'group': groups})
    result = (df.loc[df['group'] != 0]
                .groupby('group')['times']
                .agg({'start':'first','end':'last'}))
    return result

ts = make_ts(20, 5)
result = find_groups(ts)
```

yields

```
          start       end
group                    
1      0.242640  0.242640
2      0.579956  0.588791
3      0.747126  0.942829
```

To obtain the start and end times as a list of lists you could use:

```
In [125]: result.values.tolist()
Out[125]: 
[[0.24264034406127022, 0.24264034406127022],
 [0.5799564094638113, 0.5887908182432907],
 [0.7471260123697537, 0.9428288694956402]]
```

---

Using `ndimage.label` is convenient, but note that it is also possible to compute this without `scipy`:

```
def find_groups_without_scipy(ts):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'times': ts.index, 'group': (ts.diff() == True).cumsum()})
    result = (df.loc[df['group'] % 2 == 1]
                .groupby('group')['times']
                .agg({'start':'first','end':'last'}))
    return result
```

The main idea here is to find labels for the clusters of `True`s using `(ts.diff() == True).cumsum()`. `ts.diff() == True` gives the same result as `ts.shift() ^ ts`, but is a bit faster. Taking the cumulative sum (i.e. calling `cumsum`) treats `True` as equal to 1 and `False` as equal to 0, so each time a `True` is encountered the cumulative sum increases by 1. Thus each cluster gets labeled with a different number:

```
In [111]: (ts.diff() == True).cumsum()
Out[111]: 
0.069347    0
0.131956    0
0.143948    0
0.224864    0
0.242640    1
0.372599    2
0.451989    2
0.462090    2
0.579956    3
0.588791    3
0.603638    4
0.625107    4
0.642565    4
0.708547    4
0.730239    4
0.741652    4
0.747126    5
0.783276    5
0.896705    5
0.942829    5
Name: keep, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

These are all excellent solutions but I think there may be a simpler and more generally-applicable option.

At its core, you are looking for whether a value differs from the previous one. If you compare it to itself but shifted by 1, you will get what you are looking for. You also get the benefit of speedy comparison operations.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a series
series_1 = pd.Series(['duck', 'duck', 'duck', 'duck', 'goose', 'goose', 'duck'])

# Create a copy of the series shifted by 1 space
series_2 = series_1.shift(1)

# Compare the original and shifted series to get a new "Is it an edge?" series
is_edge = series_1 != series_2

pd.DataFrame({'data': series_1, 'edge': is_edge})
```

[comparison_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DniSf.gif)

Or if it's clearer with the comparison column included:

[comparison_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VNst.gif)

And making this example speak directly to your issue with a numerical index and booleans:

```py
series_1 = pd.Series({.1: True, .2: True, .3: False, .4: False, .5: True, .6: True})
series_2 = series_1.shift(1)
is_edge = series_1 != series_2

pd.DataFrame({'original': series_1, 'shifted': series_2, 'edge': is_edge})
```

[comparison_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptjDR.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but putting this out there if somebody has a similar problem.

I recommend using the `.diff(periods=1)` method to return `True` whenever a **state change** happens in the `boolean` `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame`.

Further, if you use `.diff()` on numeric data, it will return `1.0` on a **rising edge** and `-1.0` on a **falling edge**.

```
    aquisitionTS.astype('int').diff(periods=1)

Out:

    0.577331    NaN
    0.611298    0.0
    0.645255    0.0
    0.679218    0.0
    0.716538    0.0
    0.784453    1.0
    0.784453    0.0
    0.818417    0.0
    0.852379    0.0
    0.886336    0.0
    0.920301    0.0
    0.954259   -1.0
    dtype: float64
```

To return the indices you then retrieve them by applying a conditional, e.g. for rising edge detection:

```
acquisitionTs.index[acquisitionTs > 0]

Out: 

Float64Index([0.954259], dtype='float64')
```